# Is it possible to call getPanoramaByLocation without the JavaScript API?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I want to do some server side queries on the results of getPanoramaByLocation before I use it to show the streetview to the user.

Is there a way to call getPanoramaByLocation another way?
(May through another API, HTTP Request or something else?)

I need the contents of the StreetViewPanoramaData returned by that, not the actual image.

Comment: Interesting problem! I'm trying to use google api to server side you have found a solution?

Answer (score -1):

HTTP Street View API

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/

Found it with a simple google search.

Comment: This will get the image, not the contents of the StreetViewPanoramaData object I'm searching for.